# Do players get points into ATP ranking even for matches in qualifying rounds

Tags: tennis, ranking, atp

All (or at least almost all) tournaments at ATP level have a qualifying competition, from which players can get into the main draw.

Do players get some points if they win a match in the qualifying rounds? If not, do at least winners of the qualifying get points? (IIRC the players who enter main draw get points even if they are defeated in the first round already.)

---

Both [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATP_Rankings#Current_points_distribution_.282009_-_present.29) and [2014 ATP Rulebook](http://www.atpworldtour.com/~/media/DAB9C80F5DA74B7C9D0660541B9471CE.ashx) mention additional qualifying points. (For example, 25 points in Grand Slams.)

The exact quote from rulebook is this:

> Players qualifying for the main draw through the qualifying competition shall receive
>   qualifying points in addition to any points earned, as per the following table,
>   with the exception of Futures.

I am not sure whether I understand this correctly. Is this the number of points that a player who qualified to the main draw receives? (In addition to the points he receives from the competition.) So the players who do not qualify do not receive any points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, players can receive rankings points for winning qualifying round matches. The amount of points they win typically depends on how many matches they win and what level of tournament it is - a 250, 500, 1000 (Masters) or 2000 (grand slam).

An easy way to see what kind of points are awarded is to go to a tournament profile page for a tournament on the ATP's website and click on the "Points & Prize Money" tab (it's a little further down on each of the tournament profile pages). It shows a breakdown of the prize money and points awarded for each level of results (both singles & doubles).

Here's a couple of quick examples for the 2 tournaments being held this week in Barcelona (a 500 level event) and Bucharest (a 250 level event)

[Bucharest](http://www.atpworldtour.com/Tennis/Tournaments/Bucharest.aspx): 12 points for making it through qualifying and into the main draw, 6 points for making it into the last round of qualifying.

[Barcelona](http://www.atpworldtour.com/Tennis/Tournaments/Barcelona.aspx): 10 points for making it through qualifying and into the main draw, 4 points for making it into the last round of qualifying.

I believe the reason for the difference in points has to do with how many rounds of qualifying are actually held - only 2 qualifying rounds were held in Barcelona, while 3 rounds of qualifying were held in Bucharest.

Answer (score 2):

I think that it might be useful to illustrate this also with examples.

At [2014 BMW Open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_BMW_Open#Point_distribution) it was possible to get 250 points for winning the tournament. Winning qualifying meant 12 points. (It is a part of the ATP World Tour 250 series.) Martin Kližan won both [qualifying and the whole competition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_BMW_Open_%E2%80%93_Singles).

He got for this tournament 262 points, as you can see in his ranking breakdown saved in 
[internet archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20150411055929/http://www.atpworldtour.com/Tennis/Players/Top-Players/Martin-Klizan.aspx?t=rb) and in the following screenshot [image: screenshot]